# How can I display my reversed array using the onClick event in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, onclick, dom-events

I pulled data from an API and mapped it but I am wanting to reverse the order when the user clicks MARKET CAP. I want the user to click the

`<div>MARKET CAP</div>`

Down in the code I am wanting to replace this array I am mapping: 
`{props.coins.filter(searchingFor(search)).map...`
with the reversed one I made:

```
const [reverseCoin, setReverseCoin] = useState( 
 [...coin].filter(searchingFor(search)).reverse()
);
```

I have no idea how to replace the original data with the reversed one so any suggestions would be great. I'm using React, styled components and hooks. Here's my code:

```
import Button from "../../UI/Forms/Button/Button";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Icon from "../../assets/images/sort-solid.svg";
import SearchIcon from "../../assets/images/search-solid.svg";
import * as Styles from "../../components/Table/Tables.styles";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./PriceList.scss"; 


function searchingFor(search) {
return function(x) {
 return x.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || false;
};
} 

//MY FUCTIONAL COMPONENT*************

//one prop has been passed to this which I called it "coins"

const PriceList = props => {
console.log(props.coins);
const [coin, setCoin] = useState([]);
const [color, setColor] = useState("");
const [MarketCapLow, setMarketCapLow] = useState(false);
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

/// this is the variable that holds the reversed array

const [reverseCoin, setReverseCoin] = useState( 
 [...coin].filter(searchingFor(search)).reverse()
);
const timeIntervels = ["1H", "24H", "1W", "1M", "1Y"];

useEffect(() => {
 setCoin(props.coins);
}, [props.coins]);

const updateSearch = e => {
 setSearch(e.target.value);
};



const handleClick = name => {
 setColor(name);
};

//creating a table for my data********

return (
 <TableContainer>
   <SearchBarMainContainer>
     <SearchBarContainer>
       <SearchInputContainer>
         <img
           src={SearchIcon}
           width="20"
           height="20"
           style={{ marginRight: "16px" }}
         />

         <SearchBarInput
           type="text"
           value={search}
           onChange={updateSearch}
           placeholder="Search coins..."
         />
       </SearchInputContainer>
       <SearchPriceChange>
         {timeIntervels.map(d => (
           <SearchPriceChangeItems
             id={d}
             onClick={() => {
               handleClick(d);
             }}
             className={color === d ? "purple" : "black"}
           >
             {d}
           </SearchPriceChangeItems>
         ))}
       </SearchPriceChange>
     </SearchBarContainer>
   </SearchBarMainContainer>

   <Styles.Tablestyles>
     <tbody>
       <Styles.TableRowStyles bg>
         <Styles.TabelHeadingStyles bg>#</Styles.TabelHeadingStyles>
         <Styles.TabelHeadingStyles bg>NAME</Styles.TabelHeadingStyles>
         <Styles.TabelHeadingStyles bg>PRICE</Styles.TabelHeadingStyles>
         <Styles.TabelHeadingStyles bg>CHANGE</Styles.TabelHeadingStyles>
         <Styles.TabelHeadingStyles bg>
           <Styles.MarketCap
             onClick={() => {
               setMarketCapLow(!MarketCapLow);

             }}
           >
             <div>MARKET CAP</div>
             <CoinIcon width height src={Icon} />
           </Styles.MarketCap>
         </Styles.TabelHeadingStyles>
         <Styles.TabelHeadingStyles bg>TRADE</Styles.TabelHeadingStyles>
       </Styles.TableRowStyles>

       {props.coins.filter(searchingFor(search)).map(coin => {
         const {
           rank,
           logo_url,
           name,
           ["1d"]: { price_change_pct },
           currency,
           price,
           market_cap
         } = coin;
         const newMarketPct = (price_change_pct * 100).toFixed(2);
         const newPrice = Math.floor(price * 100) / 100;
         const newMarketCap =
           Math.abs(market_cap) > 999999999
             ? Math.sign(market_cap) *
                 (Math.abs(market_cap) / 1000000000).toFixed(1) +
               "B"
             : Math.sign(market_cap) * Math.abs(market_cap);
         return (
           <Styles.TableRowStyles key={rank}>
             <Styles.TabelDataStyles>{rank}</Styles.TabelDataStyles>
             <Styles.TabelDataStyles grey flex>
               <CoinIcon style={{ marginRight: "12px" }} src={logo_url} />
               {name} ({currency})
             </Styles.TabelDataStyles>

             <Styles.TabelDataStyles>${newPrice}</Styles.TabelDataStyles>

             <Styles.TabelDataStyles
               style={
                 price_change_pct.charAt(0) === "-"
                   ? { color: "#ff2734" }
                   : { color: "#23cc9a" }
               }
             >
               {newMarketPct}%
             </Styles.TabelDataStyles>
             <Styles.TabelDataStyles>${newMarketCap}</Styles.TabelDataStyles>

             <Styles.TabelDataStyles>
               <Link to={`/prices/${coin.currency}`}>
                 <Button padding style={{ width: "60%" }}>
                   Trade
                 </Button>
               </Link>
             </Styles.TabelDataStyles>
           </Styles.TableRowStyles>
         );
       })}
     </tbody>
   </Styles.Tablestyles>
 </TableContainer>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend just using a flag stored in your state to toggle how the array is displayed. This allows you to avoid storing both arrays in your state when they're essentially the same data.  You'd of course need to make a click handler to change the value of the `reversed` flag and place it wherever you want the click to occur, but I don't see where that is in your code.

```
[reversed, setReversed] = useState(false);

...
// declare this variable somewhere inside your component outside the return statement. 
// You have create a copy to prevent reverse() from mutating the prop in place.
const displayedCoins = reversed ? Array.from(props.coins).reverse() : props.coins;

...

{displayedCoins.filter(searchingFor(search)).map((coin) => { ... });
```